# Why does hasOne and BelongTo relationships load only ids but not the models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I've got a problem with relations in Laravel 9.14 Eloquent.

I have two models **File** and **Project** with coresponding tables in MySql database files and projects.

Project migration

```
Schema::create('projects', static function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('theme');
        $table->foreignId('discipline_id')->constrained('disciplines');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
        $table->string('external_id');
        $table->foreignId('preview')->nullable()->constrained('files');
        $table->date('publish_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

File migration

```
Schema::create('files', static function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('original_name');
        $table->string('extension');
        $table->string('mime_type');
        $table->integer('size')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Project has field which is related to the File model called '**preview**'. Project, basically can have only one preview file. So I did these relatioins in models:

```
class Project extends Model


public function preview(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(File::class, 'preview', 'id');
}

class File extends Model

public function previewProject(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Project::class, 'preview', 'id');
}
```

When i try to get preview of a project this way (controller method):

```
public function index(): Factory|View|Application
{
    $userId = auth()->user()->id;
    $projects = User::find($userId)->projects()->with(['user', 'preview'])->get();

    //dd($projects->first()->user);
    ddd($projects->first()->preview);

    return view('user.index', [
        'projects' => $projects
    ]);
}
```

Instead of File model object I get only integer id of File. Queries, however, look right:

[queries image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvOJD.png)

What is the problem here?

Comment: May be intended by framework to save performance. Lazy loading can load data when needed.

Comment: So what does the `dd()` show? Also, you don't need to do a database lookup to get a user you already have. `auth()->user()->projects...`

Comment: @MarkusZeller, maybe, but query proceed. It doesn't look like right case here.

Comment: @miken32, dd() shows single integer of 1. Thanks on the advice for optimization.

Comment: Oh I see the problem; your database column name is the same as the relationship name. Your column should really be called `file_id` to stick with Laravel conventions.

Comment: @miken32, is that a problem? I mean can i avoid this convention?

Comment: You can, but you're finding out why it's a bad idea. Just don't name your relationship the same as a database column.

Comment: @miken32, i dont want to name it like file_id since ill have more relations with files table in futher development, so ill have to name columns differently anyway. If there is a way to  stick with custom name for column, can I have a clue? :)

Comment: Like I said, just don't give your relationship the same name as a database column.

Comment: @Lazzytchik you can name it `preview_id` since that what it is, instead of `preview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error, the integer your are getting is the value of the attribute but by "chance" both your attribute and relation have the same name.

Either change the relation name:

```
class Project extends Model

public function previewFile(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(File::class, 'preview', 'id');
}
```

```
public function index(): Factory|View|Application
{
    $projects = auth()->user()->projects()->with(['user', 'previewFile'])->get();

    //dd($projects->first()->user);
    ddd($projects->first()->previewFile);

    return view('user.index', [
        'projects' => $projects
    ]);
}
```

Or change the attribute name

```
Schema::create('projects', static function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('theme');
        $table->foreignId('discipline_id')->constrained('disciplines');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
        $table->string('external_id');
        $table->foreignId('preview_id')->nullable()->constrained('files');
        $table->date('publish_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

```
class Project extends Model

public function preview(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(File::class, 'preview_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Brilliant idea, wish I'd thought of it.

Comment: @miken32 dont be salty, started writing the answer 25 minutes ago, has a call from a coworker that delayed it. You're not the only one with answers...

Comment: Love you guys. Changed the column name, and it works. Thank you both :)